# getting the raw data from a jQuery parseXML tag. Safari error

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing, safari

I'm having the following problem. In a callback from a jQuery get function I have the following code.

```
x = $.parseXML(data)
xmlDoc = $(x)
y = xmlDoc.find("message")
msg = y.html()

if msg == "MISSING FILE"
    # do something about the missing file
else
    # xmlDoc IS the document I want.
```

In other words, I'm getting something back from the server. If it's an XML document with "message" tag that says "MISSING FILE" then I handle it. If not I use that XML document as normal.

This code works fine in Firefox. But in Safari, in the MISSING FILE case jQuery blows up when I try to take y.html() giving the following error :

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.innerHTML.replace')
```

It looks like the value of y is

```
[<message>MISSING FILE</message>]
```

but jQuery on Safari can't do an .html() on it.

Comment: can you check the length of `y.length` before trying to get the html

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's a list of 1 item. Which is what I'd expect. 

Are you saying just test for the existence of a "message" tag rather than try to get the contents of it? I suppose that would be a workaround, but I should surely be able to get the contents of tags, no?

Comment: yes.... I just wants to make sure it is able to find the element... so if you try a `console.log(y.length)` and it returns 1 then we can think about why `.html()` is not working else we will have to figure out why `find()` is not working...

Comment: also whether it is working in other browsers and `data` is a string, isn't it?

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML that is $.get is receiving?

Comment: also what is the `[]` surrounding the xml... can you share some more context regarding how the xml is fetched from server

Comment: @ArunPJohny XML is fetched from server with jQuery.ajax(). This code is in the "success" callback. I assume data is a string. It prints like one to the console.log. And yes, it's working fine on Firefox. The [] comes with the console.log of the result of the find() ... I assume it's an array.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield . The XML that's coming back is basically :

<xml><message>MISSING FILE</message></xml>

The xmlParse doesn't seem to have a problem with that. Nor the find on the result of the parse. It's the html() that blows up.

Comment: if it is a ajax request then set the `dataType: 'xml'` for the ajax request so that you can get a parsed document in your handler and you don't have to parse it yourself

Comment: again did you check the value of length and what about the `[]` ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried the dataType: 'xml' ... that doesn't seem to have made a difference. :-(

The length of the array that's returned by the find() is 1, which is what I'd expect.  The value of what find() returns is printed to the console as : [<message>MISSING FILE</message>]

The [] is there because what find() returns *is* an array. (If I do typeof it tells me "object").

Comment: @interstar can you `console.log($($.parseXML(data.toLowerCase())).find('message')[0])` ?

Comment: @interstar and if my above console.log is still undefined can you do this: `console.log($($.parseXML(data.toLowerCase())).find('> * > *'))`

Comment: did you try it in any other browsers..

Comment: @AdamMerrifield It prints "<message>missing file</message>" (my quote marks)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've tried Firefox on Linux and Mac (works on both). And Chromium on Linux (works too). Haven't been able to try IE yet.

Comment: @interstar try changing your top 4 lines to `msg = $($.parseXML(data.toLowerCase())).find('message')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Yes. That's the problem. In Firefox msg comes out as "missing file" while in Safari it's undefined. innerHTML doesn't seem to exist for that fragment in Safari whereas it does in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks to prompting from @AdamMerrifield and @ArunPJohny I did some more investigation into the keys of the object that find() returned.

On Safari it definitely doesn't have an innerHTML.

Eventually I found that

```
x = $($.parseXML(data.toLowerCase())).find('message')[0]
msg = x["textContent"]
```

does the trick. The ["textContent"] seems to produce the same result on Chromium and Firefox on Linux, Safari and Firefox on Mac and Chrome on my Android tablet.

Still need to test on IE (where it may all go horribly wrong).